# SQL Server Datetime variables returning null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @DispDateTime datetime

SELECT @DispDateTime = table1.U_dispDate + convert(datetime, right('0'+convert(varchar, table1.U_dispTime/100),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar,table1.U_dispTime % 100 ),2),120) 
from table1

select  table1.callID, 
        @DispDateTime, 
        table1.U_dispDate + convert(datetime, right('0'+convert(varchar, table1.U_dispTime/100),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar,table1.U_dispTime % 100 ),2),120)
from table1
```

You can see that the values in my select statement are exactly the same as what's in my variable declaration. However, my results end up looking like this:

```
callID  DispDate Variable   DispDate Calc
13      NULL                2016-04-04 07:07:00.000
15      NULL                2016-04-04 09:11:00.000
16      NULL                2016-04-04 07:10:00.000
19      NULL                2016-04-04 08:27:00.000
21      NULL                2016-04-04 07:39:00.000
23      NULL                2016-04-04 07:06:00.000
24      NULL                2016-04-04 10:20:00.000
25      NULL                2016-04-04 09:23:00.000
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I'm like 98% sure it's something simple and I'm actually an idiot, but it's the second time I've run into this issue in just a couple days. (It's also the first time, as far as memory serves, that I've had to use Datetime variables, so it could just as likely be something I don't know).

EDIT:

A) The reason that the times are stored as nvarchar is because that's what is dictated by the system (SAP Business One, if that matters). It's not something that I can change.

B) I think that what I really want to do is use a CTE, and that will fix my problem. I guess I just forgot how variables work or something (I.E. not set by row, but set once and then ran).

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: The absolute best option would be to stop storing dates as varchars in the first place. Another thing to note is you didn't specify the length of your varchars. This means it uses the default, which can change based on context. It is best to always specify the length. As posted there doesn't seem to be an issue. Can you post some sample data that can recreate this issue so we can help you fix it?

Comment: What `SELECT @DispDateTime = ...` should mean? You need (can) select only one value in `@DispDateTime` and you are trying to write whole column :) Try use `TOP 1` or determine one significant value for this variable.

Comment: Verify SELECT  table1.U_dispDate,convert(datetime, right('0'+convert(varchar, table1.U_dispTime/100),2)+':'+right('0'+convert(varchar,table1.U_dispTime % 100 ),2),120) from table1
 select table1.callID.   ....... Is it returns NULL for any column

Comment: I guess I just forgot how variables work. It's been a long month working onsite at a client... Brain is beginning to burn. The solution is just to use a CTE, I think. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @SeanLange, see my Edit A) above for why that's not a viable option. (In short, SAP Business One stores times as varchars, and if you change it, the system will freak out and potentially stop working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have multiple results for your variable `@DispDateTime`.

You need a unique result for `@DispDateTime`.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @DispDateTime = table1.U_dispDate + ...
```

or a where clause.

Comment: he has multiple results - the second query uses same table and returns a lot of rows